# Creating a Windows 7 image with Ghost to install from CD?

Tags: windows-7, disk-image, norton-ghost

I have about 50 identical laptops that need to all be running Windows 7 with some extra programs and drivers.

My boss is telling me to prepare one laptop, then use Ghost to create a bootable CD from its hard drive.

I've never heard of Ghost being used to make a CD that can deploy Windows, is that possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Search for how to use sysprep

Answer (score 2):

You're simply creating a backup image of a single installation and restoring that to multiple machines. Of course, if you don't have Volume License Keys available, you'll need to (re)activate Windows on each laptop with its own key.

Additionally, to handle things like ensuring each laptop on the network has a distinct computer name, it's better if you run SysPrep before deploying the image. If you have Ghost Corporate Edition you can also GhostCast the image to multiple PCs over the network.

There are lots of tutorials available; see [here](http://www.symantec.com/support/ghosttutorial/GhostTutorials.html) and [here](http://anebg.net/2008/07/01/successfully-deploy-a-ghost-image-to-many-computers-at-the-same-time/) for example.

Comment: +1 (+10 if I could) for ghostcast. If you have it, use it. If not the price for it will be alot lot lower then time ---wasted--- needed to image 50 laptops.   Make a fat image. Sysprep, ghostcast with muticast option.  Boot a dozen laptops (as many as you have room for on your tables), image them at the same time.